# Data Structures for a fastly changing stream and K largest elements

Tags: arrays, data-structures, coding-efficiency

I'm given a stream of data which is of volume in billions and they are coming in as insertion, deleting and modifying request. What data structures should I use to do these 3 operations in O(1) time ? And also 1 in every 2hrs there's a request to find the K largest elements present in that data structure at that particular point in time.

NOTE: K can be different for different requests.

I was thinking of using dict/hashmaps for storing the indexes of elements while insertion in an array and then deletion and modifications using the dict from that array in O(1) time.

Comment: If you only care about the K largest elements, and are allowed to discard other elements, then a min-heap is the best data structure. The operations will be in O(log(K)) time, not O(1), but if K is small, then log(K) is very small.

Comment: Nope I need to keep all elements until they are deleted. And the volume is in billions/second so it's not quite efficient to make a heap after 2hrs with all those elements.

Comment: If there's any way to use another data structure with those 2 mentioned above that maintains data in sorted order, for me to retrieve k largest elements.

Comment: Billions ***per second***?????

Comment: The size of the heap is at most K, not billions. It's a min-heap. You build a heap with the first K elements, then everytime a new element is added, you delete the smallest element. This way, you're always only keeping the highest K elements.

Comment: Yes this was asked to me in an interview and heap was my answer, but storing elements in heap wasn't desired answer. Because we never know what the K might be in the coming request, so we might need to store all elements in heap then.

Comment: your first problem is the billions. If you need to keep billions of anything you need external storage. So in the real world i'd dump it into a DB and let it do the heavy lifting. 

Now if there's some sort of more reasonable limit (max-K) then you could look into the hashmap solution but you'd still need to cull the list or you're going to run out of RAM.